# Applying an Index to a Blob/Longtext field

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm, indexing, mysql-error-1170

I am trying to create an index on a particular text string using Hibernate annotations. What I am currently doing is:

```
@Index(name="guid_index")
@Column(length=1400)
private String myGUID;
```

However, since the length of the column is 1400, this maps to SQL using the `longtext` type. hbm2ddl is able to create the table without mishap, but when it tries to create the index, I get:

```
Unsuccessful: create index guid_index on table_name (myguid);
BLOB/TEXT column 'myguid' used in key specification without a key length
```

How can I create an index on this column using Hibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initially thought that [HHH-4389](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4389) was what you're looking for but your case seems to be a different issue: Hibernate is simply not generating the expected DDL statement. I would open a new Jira issue.

Comment: Actually the issue you linked is precisely what the problem is, and I will take that to mean there is no solution until the attribute is added to the `@Index` tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify a length of index.
Maximum length depends on storage engine, but usually it's not more than 1000 bytes,
if charset is utf-8, you have to divide maximum lengh by 3.

create index guid_index on table_name (myguid (1000) );

It's good enough for WHERE field LIKE 'prefix%' and WHERE field = 'text' conditions.

Comment: How do I do this using Hibernate, though?

Comment: How do we get index of more than length 1000 bytes?